# Extending module modal_forms for any content type field?

Tags: 7, entities, javascript

Has this been done or in another module?

I'd like a lightbox to appear for a particular field.

Alternatives I'm working on are to use the bootstrap lightbox (extension library) and some jquery, but would prefer something not tied to a theme.

Comment: Are you already using [`modal_forms()`](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) to handle forms? Maybe I'm missing something, but 'for any content type field' sounds like you're using this to display content, rather than a form? Can you be more specific about your end goal?

Comment: I want to be able to remind a user to enter data into a specific field before leaving the page, so I would want to fire this behaviour on a 'leaving page' or 'click' event (via JQuery / Drupal behaviours). Specifically I'm using the fivestar vote module and would like to prompt the user to vote on the content of the page.